# Asking windows credentials in my C# program?

Tags: c#

I'm building a software application and it was requested that a user/pass system be implemented with it for security reasons. I'm implementing it in Visual Studio and was curious to if it was possible that I prompt the windows login/pass be used instead of having to build my own structure? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please specify whether you are writing a desktop application (or ASP.NET?)

Comment: Sorry, it's a desktop app.

Comment: If your users are on active directory you don't even need to prompt, you can access the windows identity and group membership in code or declaritively with PrincipalPermission.

Answer (score 5):

What you're looking for is the Windows API [CredUIPromptForCredentials](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375177(v=vs.85).aspx). Here is how you use it from C# - [PInvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/credui.creduipromptforcredentials)

However, note that this returns the plaintext username and password to your application. This might be a security issue depending on if your user trusts your app or not.

I don't know any way to invalidate the current credentials so Windows forces a prompt for internal NTLM/Kerberos auth.

Comment: I think the current and up-to-date function is `CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials`, which is a bit more extensible ([MSDN doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375178(v=vs.85).aspx)), but this is the right answer

Comment: Thanks a ton! This looks like it will cover my needs!

Comment: After I got in from work I started looking through and I actually can't get this to work for me. I may be missing something glaringly obvious. Does anyone have an application that uses this successfully that I can skim?

Comment: What was the issue? Are you not able to get the P/Invoke to work or something else?